# If I install matplotlib pandas module produce error and vice versa in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I work on tensorflow_gpu in virtual environment. I use jupyter notebook. I import the following modules,

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
```

At first it shows an error "`ImportError: No module named 'pandas'.`", so I did as follow in my virtual environment,

```
conda update python
conda install python=3.5
```

Then I was able to import pandas without any issues, but then I got an error with `no module named 'matplotlib'`. So I installed  `conda install -c conda-forge matplotlib` in the virtual environment, but then again getting error about pandas module, `No module named 'pandas'`.
I am confused. Thanks if anyone could help me to explain why this is happening and how to solve it.

Comment: pandas is not present in your envirinment, do a `conda list pandas` , install pandas for the current environment , `conda install pandas=0.24.2`

Comment: okay that works. I dont know then why working pandas module stopped working at first. Anyway thanks!!